# Using generics with GSON

Tags: java, generics, gson

I am using GSON to decode JSON into an object of type T e.g.

```
public T decode(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType());
}
```

This however returns an exception -

java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected type. 
Expected one of: 
java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType,
java.lang.reflect.GenericArrayType,
but got: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl, for type token: T

I thought that by using TypeToken I avoided Type Erasure.

Am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370768/using-a-generic-type-with-gson

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, I fail to see how it's useful to wrap Gson like that.

As to your problem, the information about generic type `T` itself is not available during runtime. It's been erased. It's only available during compile time. You want to parameterize it with the actual type instead like `new TypeToken<List<String>>`.

Due to lack of reified Generics in Java (it isn't possible to do a `T t = new T()`), Gson itself is forced to use the `TypeToken` approach, as you see. Otherwise Gson would have done it in a much more elegant manner.

In order to be able to pass the actual type around, you've to reinvent the same thing as `TypeToken` is already doing. And this makes no sense :) Just reuse it or just use Gson straight without wrapping it in some helper class like that.

Comment: I was detaching the actual use of GSON from the mechanism that uses it. I have an ObjectDecoder interface with method decode(String json). This means I can switch between different implementations e.g. GSON, Jackson etc. I then use Guice to inject the dependency in to the mechanism.

Comment: Your best bet is really to reuse Gson's `TypeToken` as class or method argument or at least reinvent it if you don't want a 3rd party dependency being exposed in your API. [It's open source by Apache license](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java?spec=svn2&r=2). [Background explanation here](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener).

Answer (score 5):

I think the first answer is not pointing out the actual solution: you MUST also pass Class instance along with T, like so:

```
public T decode(String json, Class<T> cls) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, cls);
}
```

This is because 'T' here is a type VARIABLE, not a type reference; and only used by compiler to add implicit casts and verify type compatibility. But if you pass actual class it can be used; and compiler will check type compatibility to reduce chance of mismatch.

Alternatively you could take in TypeToken and pass it; but TypeToken must be constructed with real type, not a type variable; type variable is of little use here. But if you do want to wrap things you wouldn't want caller to use TypeToken (which is a Gson type).

Same wrapping mechanism would work with other libs like Jackson, which you mentioned.

Comment: This won't work for parameterized classes where this question is all about. There's no such thing like `Map<String, Object>.class`, only `Map.class`. See also the "background explanation" link in the comment in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of this issue, it's just that question did not suggest it was a parameterized class so simple answer seemed sufficient. It is a pity that JDK does not have equivalent of type token (type reference etc; each lib/framework having to define its own).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to use the json parser and break it into pieces

```
public static <TT> PushObj<TT> fromJSON(String json, Class<TT> classType)
{
    JsonObject jObj = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
    String type = jObj.get("type").getAsString();
    JsonObject job = jObj.get("object").getAsJsonObject();
    TT obj = new Gson().fromJson(job, classType);
    return new PushObj<TT>(type, obj);
}
```

Where the object structure is:
{String:Type, Generic:Object}

And the variables are:
jObj is the JSONObject of the string passed in
and job is the JSONObject of the generic object

So i used the json parser to get the type separately, and reflection for the object.