# Gson: parse generic collections

Tags: java, generics, gson

Is it possible to create a method, that parses a generic collection from jsson? My aproach above doesn't work, because at runtime gson returns an ArrayList of LinkedHasmaps here, however there is no errors at compile time.

```
private <T> ArrayList<T> readArray(String json)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type collType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {
    }.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, collType);
}
```

I have already looked at some similar questions here like: [Using a generic type with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370768/using-a-generic-type-with-gson), but I found no solution, that really works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeToken stuff requires you to have the type parameters fixed at compile time. Like `ArrayList<String>` or something. `ArrayList<T>` will not work.

If you can get the class object for T passed in somehow at runtime, then you can try the solution I suggested in [How do I build a Java type object at runtime from a generic type definition and runtime type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111899/)

Answer (score 2):

It appeared to be really simpler than most people thought:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Person>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Person> persons = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);
```

No need to copy ParameterizedTypeImpl class as newacct suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, in v2.1, if you don't do anything, it will be deserialized a `List<Map<String,Object>>`

You can register a TypeAdapterFactory for that Collection type and then determine to what kind of objects this should be actually deserialized.