# writing a function that needs Class.class as a parameter in java

Tags: java, class, generics

I want to write a function that needs a Class.class as a parameter

example:

```
class MyObject{


  public whatTypeGoesHer MyFunction(something1, something2){
//do something with parameters
}

}

class MyObject1{
      MyObject object = new MyObject();

       MyObject1 object2 = object.MyFunction(MyObject1.class,something else);

}
```

this type of invokation is what i want to achieve, how do i define "MyFunction" to accept this type of parameter?

what should be instead of "whatTypeGoesHere"?

EDIT:

Let me rephrase the question

1. i want to deserialize classes from JSON using GSON
   however, i find myself writing the exact same methods in every class i want to deserialize with the difference of the class name

this is my code:

```
public static User fromJSON(String json, Class<?> className) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.serializeNulls();
    User g1 = builder.create();
    User user = g1.fromJson(json, className.getClass());
    return user;
}
```

and its invokation in the used class

```
User user =   User.fromJSON(json,User.class);
```

I want to put the "fromJSON" method to some utils class, because in every class it is EXACTLY the same,with the difference of the class name that it returns

how do i do that?

Comment: Note that according to Java Coding style methods should start using lower letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
  public <T> void MyFunction(Class<T> something1, SomeOtherType  something2){
  // T= type parameter inside method
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure? T could be treated as a Type inside the method. Please see java Generic

Comment: thank you! I was missing "<T>" declaration in my method, that's why it didn't work

Comment: Should I deserve +1 from you guys! :)

Answer (score 10):

You need a parameter of type `Class<?>`:

```
public void myFunction(Class<?> something1, SomeOtherType something2)
```

You should go through [Reflection Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html)

Comment: Parameter, not argument. The argument is `MyObject1.class`.

Comment: PS. This will not compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet. OOPs. Fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vash: Well we don't know what the OP wants for `something2`, which is hardly Rohit's fault...

Comment: @Vash. Well, that part is not relevant at all. OP is intrested in how to pass `.class` as argument. I guess he be knowing what type to give for 2nd parameter. And `Object` is not always a good guess.

Comment: @Vash: There is *no* evidence of that at all. All we know about the argument is "something else", which could be anything. Basically, it's irrelevant to the question, as far as I can see.

Comment: this type crashes the application

Comment: @LenaBru. Which Java version are you using? And what do you mean by crashes. Please elaborate. Do you get some exception? error?

Comment: Do you get any exception or error? How are you using that parameter?

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5370998/2136812
thanks all for helping out!

Comment: @LenaBru. Ah! Good that you found a solution. I haven't used GSon. So, no idea about that. :)