# GSON using Java generics

Tags: java

I am trying to get right a method called fromJSON using the [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
public <T> T fromJSON( String object, Class<T> classObject )
{
    return gson.fromJson( object, classObject );
}
```

The fact is that I have some classes that one member could be defined using Java generics. For example I can create a `new ValidationResult<User>(), ValidationResult<Image>() or ListResult<User>(), ListResult<Image>()`, etc... so the problem I'm facing is that I need to tell GSON which T it should use. Here is where I am running in an issue, cause my current code is converting the JSON object into a `ValidationResult` or `ListResult`, but the generic object is not treated as `User`, `Image`, etc. It is just converted to a `LinkedTreeMap` for example.

I tried some answers I have found in Stackoverflow, but I still am not able to get it right.

[Using a generic type with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370768/using-a-generic-type-with-gson) 
[Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type) 
[Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)

Can someone put myself in the right path? If possible share some code that I can use as guide.

Comment: Does the class declaring your `fromJson` method have a type parameter `T`?

Comment: So this is a generic method right? you have to declare the type before using it, try `public <T> T fromJSON(String object, Class<T> classObject)`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It has no <T> cause I don't want to create a new instance each time I want to use the fromJSON method with a different class.

Comment: Then do what @neevek suggests and make the method generic.

Comment: Thanks SotiriosDelimanolis and @neevek. The question has been updated. GSON still ignoring the type. How should I pass the ValidationResult<User> for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of type erasure `ValidationResult` and `ValidationResult<User>` are the same type. There will only ever be one `Class` object for that type. Because Gson only knows about `ValidationResult` through that `Class` object, it has to use a default for the generic type. In this case, it uses a `LinkedHashMap`.

The easiest solution is to provide a `TypeToken`, which is kind of a hack to get around type erasure (but not really). You can use it like so

```
gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ValidationResult<User>>() {}.getType());
```

Through the `Type`, Gson has access to the generic type argument. Note how I've hardcoded the type `User` as an argument. You have to use an actual type here for Gson to get the actual type. If you use a generic type parameter, Gson will get a generic type parameter as a value and again will not know how to use it.  I explain why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type).

Another solution is to create a subtype of `ValidationResult` like

```
public class UserValidationResult extends ValidationResult<User> {}
```

and pass the `Class` object of that to your method.